# Can not use && operator in Runtime.exec() + linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, terminal, runtime.exec

I'm trying to run an executable from Java with the code pasted below. By using the && operator in the terminal I can both navigate to and run the executable with a single command. I am trying to pass the same command through the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command but it doesn't seem to like the && operator. Does anyone know a work around for this? In the code posted below I am just passing "cd && pwd" as a test case; an even simpler command but it still doesn't work. Thanks

```
try{
                int c;
                textArea.setText("Converting Source Code to XML");
                //String[] commands = {"/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /home/Parallel/HomeMadeXML", "&&", "./src2srcml --position" + selectedFile.getName() + "-o targetFile.xml"};
                String commands = "bash -c cd && pwd";
                System.out.println(commands);
                Process src2XML = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
                InputStream in1 = src2XML.getErrorStream();
                InputStream in2 = src2XML.getInputStream();
                while ((c = in1.read()) != -1 || (c = in2.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char)c);
                    }
                src2XML.waitFor();
                }
            catch(Exception exc){/*src2srcml Fail*/}
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried: `String commands = "bash -c 'cd && pwd'";`

Comment: As @anubhava indicates `bash -c cd && pwd` is parsed by the shell as `bash -c cd`, `&&`, `pwd` and you need `cd && pwd` to be passed as the argument to `-c`.

Comment: @anubhava Is that going to work?  Or is that going to execute a command with four arguments `"-c"`, `"'cd"`, `"&&"`, `"pwd'"`?  He may need to use the `exec()` that takes a `String[]` argument.  [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) implies that it uses a very simple Tokenizer and wouldn't interpret single quote marks.

Comment: I guess Using `exec()` with `String[] arguments` will be better and OP does show it in commented code as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to run a command, you have to use exactly three arguments: `bash` the executable, `-c` the flag to execute a command, and a third shell command.

You are trying to pass 5, where the last three are individual fragments of one command.

Here's an example. Note how the shell command is only one argument:

```
String[] commands = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /tmp && touch foobar" };
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(commands);
```

When executed, you'll find a file `foobar` created in your `/tmp`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Another question arises though. In the commented line I have above that defines the string 'command' one of the parameters I am trying to pass is a file chosen earlier. The call 'selectedFile.getName()' would need to happen outside of the quotes. I suppose I could concatenate the strings in another line but is there a simpler way? Thanks again

Comment: There's no simpler way, but there is a better way:  `commands = { "bash", "-c", "touch \"$1\"", "_", selectedFile.getName() };` This passes the name as an argument to the shell, accessible through `"$1"`. This way, it works no matter the filename, and doesn't have code injection security issues.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm just a bit confused. If I need the call to be structured like this:

commands = {"bash", "-c", "cd dir && ./src2srcml --position FILENAME -o targetFile.xml"} Then I need to do this: 

commands = {"bash", "-c", "cd dir && ./src2srcml --position touch \"$1\" -o targetFile.xml", selectedFile.getName()};
Is that right? If running a command can only take 3 arguments as suggested above what is the "_" for? Thanks

Comment: When using `-c`, the non-option arguments to bash are assigned to the shell's positional parameters starting from 0. Since `$0` is canonically the command name, we provide dummy name like "_". Your command would be fine if you added a dummy name.